# line 75 : if (is_array($errors))

Tags: php, shopping-cart

Error!

The following error(s) occurred:
Notice: Undefined variable: errors in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\scripts\ladies_paradise\checkout.php on line 75

Please try again.
`        
        
        
        
        Untitled Document

```
<body>
<?php

$page_title='ORDER FORM';

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
   $errors= array();
   $price=($_POST['price']);;
   $quantity=($_POST['quantity']);
   $total = $quantity * $price;
   $total = number_format ($total, 2);

// Validate the name and combat Magic Quotes, if necessary.
if (empty ($_POST['product'])) { 
   $errors[]='You forgot to enter product.';
}else{
    $pr=trim($_POST['product']);
}

 // Validate the price.
if (empty ($_POST['price'])) { 
     $errors[] ='You forgot to enter price.';
} else {
     $p=trim($_POST['price']);
} 

 // Validate the quantity.
if (empty ($_POST['quantity'])) { 
     $errors[] ='You forgot to enter quantity.';
} else {
     $q=trim($_POST['quantity']);
} 





if(empty($errors)){
require_once('checkout_connect.php');    

     $query="INSERT INTO customers(product,price,quantity)VALUES('$pr','$p','$q')";
     $result=@mysql_query($query);//Run the query.
     if($result){

       echo 'You are purchasing <b>', $c. '</b>. 
          Total price is <b>$', $total, '</b>.';
} else { // One from element was not filled out properly.
     echo  '<p><font color="orange">Please go back and fill out the form again.</font></p>';
}

 exit();

     }else{ //If it did not run OK.
       echo '<h1 id="mainhead">System Error</h1>
       <p class="error">You could not registered due to system error.We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';//Public message.
       echo '<p>'.mysql_error().'<br/><br/>'.$query.'</p>'; //Debugging message.


        exit();
     }

     mysql_close(); //Close the database connection.

  }else{ //Report the errors.

    echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Error!</h1>
    <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
    if (is_array($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $msg){ //Print each error.
       echo " - $msg<br />\n";
    }
    }
    echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p><p><br /></p>';
     }//End of if (empty($errors)) IF.
 ?>

<h2>ORDER FORM:</h2>
<form action="checkout.php" method="post">
   <p>Product: <input type="number" name="code_item" size="15" maxlength="15" value"<?php if (isset($_POST['product'])) echo $_POST['product']; ?>" /></p>
   <p>Price: <input type="number" name="price" size="15" maxlength="30" value"<?php if (isset($_POST['price'])) echo    $_POST['price']; ?>" /></p>
   <p>Quantity: <input type="number" name="quantity" size="30" maxlength="50" value"<?php if (isset($_POST['quantity'])) echo $_POST['quantity']; ?>" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
   <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />

</form>
</body>
</html>``
```

Comment: Copy-pasting an error message is not the same thing as asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Define it at the top of the document.

```
<?php

    $errors = false;
```

Alternatively, check if it is set using a ternary where assignment is necessary.

```
echo isset($errors) ? $errors: '';
```

Where `''` can be replaced with whatever assignment correlates to the requirements.

Comment: `s/ternary/conditional operator/`. And does `$errors;` on its own really function as a declaration?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In any version of PHP above 4, it does function as it's down declaration *edit* AFAIK.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: [Nope, doesn't seem so](http://ideone.com/i6Gxpf), at least not in PHP 5.4.4.

Comment: @user3078998 That's because it's not an array. Your initial conditional statement fails due to the fact that the value `$_POST['submitted']` is not set. Due to this fact, errors are never turned to an array. Debug the variable, `echo '<pre>', print_r($errors), '</pre>';`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough, could've sworn empty declarations work, oh well, I'll just remove it.

Comment: It's an empty-ish statement but there's no declaration there whatsoever.

Comment: Error!

The following error(s) occurred:

Please try again.
  
  }else{ //Report the errors.
  
    echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Error!</h1>
 <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
 if (is_array($errors)) {
 foreach ($errors as $msg){ //Print each error.
    echo " - $msg<br />\n";
 }
 }
 echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p><p><br /></p>';
  }//End of if (empty($errors)) IF.
 ?>

Comment: thank you for the help Ohgodwhy and Lightness Races in Orbit.

Comment: the line 75 has gone. but now it appears line 63 : echo '<p>'.mysql_error().'<br/><br/>'.$query.'</p>';                                                                                                                   this is my coding : echo '<h1 id="mainhead">System Error</h1>
    <p class="error">You could not registered due to system error.We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
    echo '<p>'.mysql_error().'<br/><br/>'.$query.'</p>';